# Facebook FB.api post how to specify a target

Tags: api, facebook, post, hyperlink, target

I am using FB.api OpenGraph to post a message on the user's wall. I would like the link target to be equal to '_blank' so it opens in a new tab. Is it possible ? The Facebook documentation doesn't give much details.

```
  var params = {};

  params['message'] = 'message';
  params['name'] = 'name';
  params['link'] = 'http://link';
  params['picture'] = 'http://picture';
  params['description'] = 'description';

  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
    } else {
      alert('Post ID: ' + response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I dont think that there is anything that can be done about this.  That said - the behavior that i see is that every link **will** open a new tab...

Answer (score 0):

that's something they manage themselves. there's nothing you can do. Still, AFAIK, that's the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your Apps Url in the app settings.
Im witnessing that , when the apps url was app.com
all links i shared on my users feed with the link app.com/results.php would open on the same tab and links i shared with the link www.app.com/results.php would open in a new link.
 The problem there , was , that from www.app.com , i couldnot authorize api access for some reason.
 I'll try to register both urls , and see what happens.

Comment: correcting that , when your app domain auth is www.app.com
then everything you direct in your links to app.com will open in a new tab and everything on www.app.com , on the same tab.
  It doesnt work the other way around though , if your app domain auth is app.com , all will open in the same tab.